# How to create web form using psp/sql in oracle sql developer

Tags: html, sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm working on two web pages in Oracle SQL Developer. The first page is a form that users can input information into the sporting_clubs table. The second page is a page that if inserted correctly will output a success. I'm having problems with my procedure I created called club_success as it won't work submitting the information. The first set of code is my procedure, the second set is my form web page, and the third set of code is my success page.

```
create or replace procedure club_success ( name_text varchar2,
street_text varchar2, city_text varchar2, state_text varchar2, zip_text varchar2, formbutton varchar2) is
begin
insert into sporting_clubs (name,street,city,state,zip)
values(name_text,street_text,city_text,state_text, zip_text);
commit;
select name into name_text
from sporting_clubs
dbms_output.put_line('Club Name '||name_text);
dbms_output.put_line('Street '||street_text);
dbms_output.put_line('City '||city_text);
dbms_output.put_line('State'||state_text);
dbms_output.put_line('Zip'||zip_text);

end;

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<%@page language="PL/SQL"%>
<%@plsql procedure="club_success"%>
<head>
<title>Input Club</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center"><p><h2>Sporting Clubs</h2>
<!-- Navigation Bar Links -->
<a href="http://server-name/DAD/userid.sporting_clubs">Sporting Clubs</a><br>
<hr />
<br> <!-- Start Page Content -->
<form action="http://server-name/DAD/userid.create_club" method="post">
Club Name: <input type="text" name="name_text" value="" /> <br /><br />
Street: <input type="text" name="street_text" value=""/> <br /><br />
City: <input type="text" name="city_text" value="" /> <br /><br />
State: <input type="text" name="state_text" value="" /> <br /><br />
Zip: <input type="text" name="zip_text" value="" /> <br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="formbutton" value="Submit Club Entry"/>
</form>
<!-- End Page Content -->
</body>
</html>

<%@page language="PL/SQL"%>
<%@plsql procedure="club_success"%>
<%@plsql parameter="name_text" default="null"%>
<%@plsql parameter="street_text" default="null"%>
<%@plsql parameter="city_text" default="null"%>
<%@plsql parameter="state_text" default="null"%>
<%@plsql parameter="zip_text" default="null"%>
<%@plsql parameter="formbutton" default="null"%>
<%update sporting_clubs
set name = name_text,
street = street_text,
city = city_text,
state = state_text,
zip = zip_text;
commit;%>
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN">
<html>
<head>
<title>Sporting Clubs</title>
</head>
<body>
<div align="center"><p><h1>Create Club</h1></p>
<!-- Navigation Bar Links -->
<a href="sporting_clubs">Home</a><br>
<hr /></div>
<br>
<p>Club Created!.</p>
<!-- End Page Content -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Are you getting any error? I think you don't need `formbutton` parameter as you are not using it in the stored procedure.

Comment: It's not currently outputting any of the data. I'm not sure how to set up my oracle developer to allow me to do that

Comment: I'm not sure what you're trying to do here. SQL Developer can't process php. Are you just using it as a text editor?

Comment: @eaolson I'm using psp not php.

Comment: if you are expecting `dbms_output.put_line` to display data in HTML then I doubt that can be done..... apart from that, in the HTML code there is nothing to output the data. You have only input controls in HTML to collect the data and pass to the stored procedure..